# json_decode() is not working while decoding json data

Tags: php

I want to decode json encoded data, My code output is

```
[ItemVariant] => [{"VariantID1":"36","VariantID2":"1","RevisionNumber":1,"LineNo":1},{"VariantID1":"47","VariantID2":"44","RevisionNumber":1,"LineNo":1}],
```

and i am using following code to decode it in controller file in save function

```
$variantdata = json_decode($this->request->data['ItemVariant']); ,
```

but not getting expected output, 
   please suggest me proper solution

Comment: What output you getting ?

Comment: What errors are you receiving? What value is in `$variantData`? What is the result of `json_last_error`?

Comment: Why is there a comma at the end of `$variantdata = json_decode($this->request->data['ItemVariant']);`?

Comment: Is `$this->request->data['ItemVariant']` actually a string?

Comment: print_r($this->request->data['ItemVariant']) and show your result

Comment: @RakeshSharma his first example looks like a `print_r` output, it'd be more useful if he showed us the result of `var_dump`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a unrequired "," at the end. Please remove it.

This should help:

```
<?php
$str = '[
    {
        "VariantID1": "36",
        "VariantID2": "1",
        "RevisionNumber": 1,
        "LineNo": 1
    },
    {
        "VariantID1": "47",
        "VariantID2": "44",
        "RevisionNumber": 1,
        "LineNo": 1
    }
]';
$json = json_decode($str, true);
print_r($json);
?>
```

Run the code here:
http://codepad.org/GZcCdkd2